# Missing artifact event:event:jar:1.0

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to run a simple program using jmeter apis. I have created a maven project and added all the required dependecies. But I keep getting this error.

```
Missing artifact event:event:jar:1.0
```

Earlier I was getting missing d-haven-managed-pool and I resolved it by the adding managed-pool dependency, now I'm stuck with this. What's the solution for this?

Here's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company.gls</groupId>
  <artifactId>PerformanceFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>PerformanceFramework</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_config</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_ftp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_functions</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_junit-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_ldap</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_mail</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_monitors</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_native</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_report</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_tcp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>d-haven-mpool</groupId>
        <artifactId>managed-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>d-haven-event</groupId>
        <artifactId>event</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your local repository (.m2\repository) has downloaded this dependency - *event:event:jar:1.0*.

Given the exception you face, I expect it to not be present there. I would check:

a) if the *{M2_HOME}\conf\setting.xml* has the right server, username and password. It is possible that your repo details are not set correctly

b) if the 1.0 version is actually present in the remote repo

Comment: settings.xml is configured correctly and event.jar has version 1.0.3 which I changed in the xml but still the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I found, with an `event.jar` has the wrong groupid for your project (http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|event.jar). Is it possible that `event:event:jar:1.0` is something local to your project and cached locally, or in this ... not cached?

Comment: No. It is a dependency in pom.xml of d-haven-managed-pool dependency. Earlier I was getting an error about d-haven-managed-pool. Somehow I came over it.

Comment: According to the Maven repository there was never a version "1.0" published: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22d-haven-event%22%20AND%20a%3A%22event%22. I would change it to 1.0.1 and see of that fixes the problem.